# How to pass the whole column of values inside dataGridView into method?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a dataGridView containing longitude and latitude value.

I need to make use with the value by passing it into a `DoSomethingMethod()`.

I am not familiar with dataGridView and therefore I copy all the value from dataGridView and handle it wit `List<>`

Below is my code to manipulate the data inside dataGridView

```
Public Main()
{
    List<double> lst_Long = new List<double>();
    List<double> lst_Latt = new List<double>();

    for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rows++)
    {
        lst_Long.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells["Long"].Value));
        lst_Latt.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells["Latt"].Value));            
    }

    int ColumnCount = lst_Long.Count - 1;
    int RowCount = lst_Row.Count - 1;

    //Pass the list to DoSomethingMethod
    DoSomethingMethod(lst_Long , lst_Latt, ColumnCount, RowCount);
}

DoSomethingMethod(List<double> lst_long, List<double> lst_latt, int ColumnCount, int RowCount)
{
    for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < ColumnCount; iColumn++)
    {
        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < RowCount; iRow++)
        {
             // access my latitude value and longitude value here
             double myX = lst_latt[iRow]
             double myY = lst_long[iRow]

            // do some processing here with the value, lets say....
            double myNewX = myX + 10;
            double myNewY = myY + 10;

            PassNewDataToAnotherMethod( myNewX , myNewY );
        }

    }
}
```

I would like to ask, if there is any other way to direct use and get the cell value from the dataGridView at `Columns["Long"]` and `Columns["Latt"]` and do the similar thing with out copy value from dataGridView into the list?

Thanks~

**Update**: Below is my DGV table (The data is random, not real)

[image]

**Update my own answer and this question shall close**

```
// Pass the whole dataGridView1 into method and access the value through row count.
DoSomethingMethod(DataGridView dataGridView1)
{
    for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rows++)
    {
        double myX = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells["Latt"].Value);
        double myY = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells["Long"].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to process all the `DataGridView`'s cells in the `DoSomethingMethod` method?

Comment: What is the object behind one row? Stated differently: what is the data source of the DGV? You should try to use the original objects in stead of values in the grind.

Comment: Yes. I need. Actually I can direct pass the whole 'DataGridView' into the method. And access the values inside the 'DataGridView', this would be fine for me too.

Comment: Can't you use the source which binds the grid for processing ?

Comment: Maybe the source is user manual input.

Comment: As I said, I am not familiar with `DataGridView`. I am getting the table from an excel file using `OleDbConnection` and bind the `DataGridView.Source` to the excel table.

Comment: If the datasource is a `DataTable`, you can use it in your method: `var dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;`

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing that (that comes to my mind) is using `BindingSource` with custom model, so instead of operating on rows you would operate on databound model. Something like that:

```
public class Location
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

//binding grid

```
var bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = listOfLocations; // List<Location>
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;   // thanks to binding source all changes in datagrid are
                                 // propagated to underlying data source (ie. List<Location>
```

Then you can just operate on `listOfLocations` without accessing values in cells by yourself.

Comment: my value is inside the dataGridView table, I need to read out the data and process the data.. May be I should update more details..

Comment: I understand that. My approach allow you to operate on model instead of grid, but values can be accessed/changed/deleted from grid by user and that will be propagated into models automatically.

Comment: @jhyap This is the right approach. Don't make a view implementation essential to your business logic. You should be able to achieve what you want _without_ the grid. Just the data and the method. The grid is nothing but a tool to display and maybe modify the data by user input. Imagine what happens if one day you decide to use a third-party grid component.

Comment: The `listOfLocation` is actually from an excel file. I open the excel file using `OleDbConnection` and bind excel table to `dataGridView1.DataSource`. Hence, I have my data table inside the `dataGridView1` and I can use it. But you remind me the concern of the logic, I should access the data directly from the file instead of putting it into dataGridView and access it. Erm.. this should be another question :)

Comment: @jhyap The `OleDbConnection` populates a `DataTable`, right? If so, you've got a datatable to work with.

Comment: @GertArnold today I did some study on `DataTable` too, and it cause me blur again. I usually only use `DataTable` when doing mySQL. Anyhow, I will post some questions again if I need help on that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are actually trying to achieve. Here is one more solution. Hope this solution is useful for you.

You can create a list of tuples using linq and send it to the NewDoSomething method as shown below

```
    Public Main()
    {   
        //Generate a list of Tuples using linq
        var tuples = from row in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                     select new Tuple<double, double>(
                         Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["longitude"].Value), 
                         Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["latitude"].Value));

        //Pass the tuple list to DoSomethingMethod
        DoSomethingMethod(tuples);
    }

    private void DoSomeThing(IEnumerable<Tuple<double, double>> tuples)
    {
        //Iterate through the tuples
        foreach (Tuple<double, double> tuple in tuples)
        {
            double myX = tuple.Item1;
            double myY = tuple.Item2;
        }
    }
```

Of course this code could be refined. This just shows the approach you can use.

Comment: this could be something new :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `DataTable` as the datasource, you may try this:

```
public void Main()
{
    DoSomethingMethod((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
}

private void DoSomethingMethod(DataTable dataTable)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        double myX = Convert.ToDouble(row["Latt"]);
        double myY = Convert.ToDouble(row["Long"]);
    }
}
```